# Multicast packet not received by MulticastSocket on any localhost client

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, multicast

**Intro**

There are a number of tutorials on creating a multicast publisher and receiver.

I used the one found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html) with a few modifications.

A few others:

- [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Network/0050__Java_Network_UDP_Multicast.htm)
- [here](http://staff.www.ltu.se/~peppar/java/multicast_example/)
- [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/multicastsocket-net/java-net-multicastsocket-example/)

note that these tutorials are all quite similar.

**Details:**

The server runs on port `7777` and sends datagrams to `224.0.0.0` (I tested a couple of other ip's in the multicast range: `224.0.0.0` to `239.255.255.255`, but these didn't work)

Client then joins the multicast group `224.0.0.0` and waits for a packet response (run as a thread)

*extra:* I send a message like: `123.23.13.12[host-name]:1234` as the datagram data.

**Problem:**

Multicast packets from server (on localhost) not reaching client (on localhost).

Clients include a java console application (code found below) and Android application on Android Emulator. Both clients do not receive multicast packets.

I know that the multicast packets are being sent as this is shown in [Wireshark](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Wireshark/IPv4_multicast)

Below you will find a basic example of that which I have.

**TL;DR**: Server sends multicast packets (confirmed via Wireshark) but client doesn't receive them.

Suggestions are very welcome!

**UPDATE**

Based on  `Just another Java programmer`'s comment, I check my firewall. Lo and behold, my firewall was dropping on the `input` and `forward` chains. I set this to `accept`all incoming (temporarily)

Based on `Ron Maupin`'s comments.

- I have changed the message sent to exclude the hostname, thus the message sent is `123.12.13.23:1234`
- I have changed the multicast send address to `239.254.0.0` which is within the specified range (see Ron's comment)
- the multicast port is set to `7777`
- the outgoing interface is set with `s.setInterface(InetAddress.getLocalHost())` in the `broadcastServer()` `try catch` block

With these changes applied, the client(s) still do not receive any packets.

**Code:**

Server Side (Console App):

```
String multicastAddress = "239.254.0.0", multicastPort = 7777;

private void broadcastServer() {
    String message = null;
    MulticastSocket s = null;
    InetAddress local = null, group = null;
    InetAddress[] allByName;
    try {
        local = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        s = new MulticastSocket(multicastPort);
        s.setReuseAddress(true);
        s.setInterface(local)
        s.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName(multicastAddress));
        group = InetAddress.getByName(multicastAddress);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MulticastSocket socket = s;

    // getNetworkIP() gets lan network ip
    // serverport = 1025
    message = local.getHostAddress() + ":" + String.valueOf(serverPort);
    byte[] buf = message.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, group, multicastPort);

    thdBroadcaster = new Thread(() -> {
        while (bRunServer) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                printf("[Broadcast] Broadcasting...");
                socket.send(packet);
                printf("OK\n");
                printf("");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        socket.close();
    });
    thdBroadcaster.start();
}
```

Client Side (Console app):

```
String multicastAddress = "239.254.0.0", multicastPort = 7777;

private void startServerListenerThread() {
    Thread thdServerListener = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MulticastSocket socket = null;
            InetAddress group = null;
            try {
                socket = new MulticastSocket(multicastPort);
                socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                group = InetAddress.getByName(multicastAddress);
                socket.joinGroup(group);

                handleServerBroadcasts(socket);
                socket.leaveGroup(group);
                socket.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void handleServerBroadcasts(final MulticastSocket socket) {
            while (true){
                try {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    String received = new String(packet.getData());

                    String address = received.substring(0, received.indexOf(":"));
                    String port = received.substring(received.indexOf(":") + 1);

                    System.out.println();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception x){
                    x.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thdServerListener.start();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have a software firewall active on the client?

Comment: First, `224.0.0.0` is a reserved multicast address that cannot be used. You probably want to use a multicast address in an allowed range, and that would be `239.0.0.0` to `239.255.255.255`, the Organization-Local Scope. Next, "_I send a message like: `123.23.13.12[host-name]:1234` as the datagram data_," is incorrect. That would be a DNS name, which is not allowed in multicast. You must send a message like: `123.23.13.12:1234`.

Comment: Also, you need to specify the outgoing multicast interface. The same multicast groups are used on all interfaces, and you specify which interface to use for multicast.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer see update

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for the comments and feedback, see update

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution ended up being a trivial change.

Resolving the issue was as simple as changing:

```
s = new MulticastSocket(multicastPort);
```

to

```
s = new MulticastSocket();
```

**on the server side ONLY**

Note: The firewall is a requirement, check if multicast packets are allowed through. The interface I used is localhost, not a requirement though. However this can be set by getting the specified interface you need.

**UPDATE**

EJP's comment:

I changed the port used to `8888`. This port was used to send server datagrams and for the client to connect on with their `MulticastSocket`

Comment: So how did the client succeed in sending multicasts to port 7777? Not credible.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setReuseAddress()` *after* binding the socket. It has no effect. You need to create an unbound `MulticastSocket`, call `setReuseAddress()`, and then bind it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, comment rather as your answer, helpful as it may be, does not solve the question/problem, reason for downvote.